# Angular - Add free solid icons

Tags: angular, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to use free font awesome icons in my app, but for some reason I can't add them. This is the code I'm using:

My package.json

```
 "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
 "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
 "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
```

My module

```
import { faMousePointer } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FaIconLibrary, FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

export class IconsModule {
  constructor(faService: FaIconLibrary) {
    faService.addIcons(faMousePointer, faCity);
  }
```

Before to add icons faMousePointer and faCity, faService already has a lot of icons added

[image]

But after run the line faService.addIcons...the icon faMousePointer was not added to the faService, but faCity was added.

Why I can't add faMosuePointer icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong faMousePointer  is not in free-solid-svg-icons.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/js-packages/%40fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons